# Passing Windows cmd to the Python subprocess

Tags: python, cmd, subprocess, popen

I'm trying to execute aws cli command using Pyton's subprocess

windows cmd:

```
aws --profile some_profile --region some_region ec2 describe-instances --filters Name=tag:some_tag,Values=some_value --query "Reservations[*].Instances[*].{AvailabilityZone:Placement.AvailabilityZone,Status:State.Name,Name:Tags[?Key=='Name']|[0].Value}" --output=table
```

and that's how I try to do it:

```
profile = "some_profile"
region = "some_region"
ec2_filters = "Name=tag:some_tag,Values=some_value"
ec2_query = "Reservations[*].Instances[*].{AvailabilityZone:Placement.AvailabilityZone,Status:State.Name,Name:Tags[?Key=='Name']|[0].Value}"
ec2_output_type = "table"

proc = subprocess.Popen(["aws", "--profile", profile, "--region", region, "ec2", "describe-instances", "--filters", ec2_filters, "--query", ec2_query, "--output", ec2_output_type], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
```

This is the error message:

> '[0].Value}' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
> operable program or batch file.

Comment: Try putting an extra set of quotes on your query, `'"Reservations[*].Instances[*].{AvailabilityZone:Placement.AvailabilityZone,Status:State.Name,Name:Tags[?Key=='Name']|[0].Value}'"
 `

Comment: I've tried that but it says: SyntaxError: invalid syntax. I also tried the other way around (single quotes inside), like "'query_here'" but then I have similar error: '[0].Value}'' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

Comment: Ohh, I didn't notice the single quotes in your command. Try triple quotes then. `ec2_query = '''"Reservations[*].Instances[*].{AvailabilityZone:Placement.AvailabilityZone,Status:State.Name,Name:Tags[?Key=='Name']|[0].Value}"'''`

Comment: This triple-quoted string will comment the value of my variable :)

Comment: I don't understand. Triple quoted strings aren't comments, they're just strings. You can use them as much as you want.

Comment: You are right but somehow it breaks that string and can't get the output from that command.

Comment: Ok I just double checked and that triple quote indeed breaks the command. I've tried it with something that works. if I use this `ec2_query = "Reservations[*].Instances[*].{AvailabilityZone:Placement.AvailabilityZone,Status:State.Name}"` it works (but of course the part that causes the problem is missing here - `Name:Tags[?Key=='Name']|[0].Value`) When I add that triple quote to that it breaks the command. So I guess I can not use what you suggested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have aws installed, so I created a mock batch file to spit back what it received. I did try my initial guesses and you're right, it often makes it difficult, but I figured it out. Sorry for not testing what I asked you to try.

Anyway, `aws.bat` contains a single line, `echo %*`, which prints back whatever the batch file receives as arguments, so we know it's working.

Then, I tried to use your command. I got the same error you got, so I modified it to:

`.\aws.bat --profile some_profile --region some_region ec2 describe-instances --filters Name=tag:some_tag,Values=some_value --query '"Reservations[*].Instances[*].{AvailabilityZone:Placement.AvailabilityZone,Status:State.Name,Name:Tags[?Key=='Name']|[0].Value}"' --output=table`

This outputted the command back, meaning it got executed correctly.

Then, I modified your code to make sure there's quotes over all the query. I used simple string concatenation to do that.

```
import subprocess
profile = "some_profile"
region = "some_region"
ec2_filters = "Name=tag:some_tag,Values=some_value"
ec2_query = (
    '"Reservations[*].Instances[*].{AvailabilityZone:Placement.AvailabilityZone,Status:State.Name,Name:Tags[?Key=='
    "'Name'" 
    ']|[0].Value}"'
)
ec2_output_type = "table"

proc = subprocess.Popen(["aws.bat", "--profile", profile, "--region", region, "ec2", "describe-instances", "--filters", ec2_filters, "--query", ec2_query, "--output", ec2_output_type])
```

This worked. Funnily, if I used triple quotes in an unorthodox manner, it worked as well.

```
ec2_query = ' '''"Reservations[*].Instances[*].{AvailabilityZone:Placement.AvailabilityZone,Status:State.Name,Name:Tags[?Key=='Name']|[0].Value}"' '''
```

Note the start, `' '''"`. I don't really know what's going on.

Anyway, the easier solution is to break up your string so the quotes don't get confusing.

Comment: Great, it works! You are right, breaking that string is propably the best solution.